# Do I need to connect default firebase domain in order to get SSL certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, deployment, axios, ssl-certificate

I've deployed the frontend of a web app to Firebase. Now when I try to make request I see that request is going to `https://the_url` but the backend link is `http://the_url` and I get the following error.

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://the_url' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://the_url. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I tried to get SSL certificate and import an certificate to AWS to make connection https, but I wasn't able to get it.

Comment: If you already managed to serve the request from https (as shown in the first part of the error message) there should not be any need to do any funny business with ssl certificates. Just make sure all requests actually use https and not http.

Comment: But the backend endpoint is not https, it's htpps. Even after I deploy with http it keeps adding 's' at the end.